# Break after x groups in table

Tags: c#, rdlc

I set up a group for a C# `rdlc` table. In the group properties there is an option to 'break before' or 'break after' the group. I want to break after four groups appear on the page.

Anyone know how to break after a certain number of groups?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in this kind of scenario, I would introduce additional field in the data source - "page number" - that would re-set when page break needed and make it first grouping criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the row number function with the context of the parent group in which you have the groups you want to break and compare that to 4 in your case.